# How do I create an Elastic Beanstalk t2.nano instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I change the default "t1.micro" selection to "t2.nano" it throws a bunch of errors telling me I can only run this environment in a VPC. I see I have a VPC running but I don't know how to put the elastic beanstalk environment in it.

Sorry if what you just read made you cringe. I'm new to this :(

Answer (score 1):

Once an Elastic Beanstalk environment has been created, it can't be moved in/out of a VPC.

You can create a new Environment for the same Application, then at the "Additional Resources" step, tick the "Create this environment inside a VPC" box. An extra step will then be added to let you select the VPC & Availability Zone.

Comment: Is there a way to change the instance type? It gives you the option, but if you change it from t1.micro to t2,nano the environment fails...

Comment: In an existing Beanstalk Environment? Yes, by going to Configuration > Instances in the Console for that environment.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just created a new `t2.nano` environment with no issues, and then switched it to a `t1.micro` also with no issues. If you're unable to do so, please provide some more details about how you're configuring the environment, how your application works, what platform you're choosing, and what you mean by "the environment fails".